# Declaring a new long array c++

Tags: c++

Am I declaring this correctly?

```
string regular = "TEST";
long[] cipher = new long[regular.length()];
```

Getting this compilation error: `expected unqualified-id before '[' token`

Comment: An array is not a pointer. A pointer is not an array.

Comment: And Java syntax is not C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

a `new` expression returns a pointer, so your `cipher` must be one:

```
long *cipher = new long[regular.length()];
```

But using raw arrays is error prone. Consider substituting `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<long> cipher(regular.length());
```

Comment: Wouldn't initializing `std::vector` with `{regular.length()}` use initializer-list constructor, and construct it, with a single element, which is of value `regular.length()`, rather than constructing it with `regular.length ()` amount of elements, as the OP wants?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius - You are correct. A side-effect of using brace initialization here. I've updated the answer to make sure the correct c'tor us called.